# Detect when the inner html of a <td> changes with javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have a table and I am dynamically add the value in each table cell from FireBase. I want to add a "flash" or "blinking" effect everytime that cell changes. So I need to be able to detect when the content of that  has changed.

Comment: ? Why not just trigger the effect from the code that updates the cell?

Comment: You need to use something like [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)/MutationEvents(old browsers)

Comment: @zhs What does this has to do with AnuglarJs?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20053557/ng-animate-animation-when-model-changes

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is still looking and stumbles across this question, I've found the solution here, posted by @Rohan Kumar, which uses the DOMSubtreeModified

[Call a Javascript function when a table change content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28044730/call-a-javascript-function-when-a-table-change-content)

```
$("#mytable").bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {
    alert("Hurrey table changed");
});
```