# Call a Javascript function when a table change content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Javascript code which format a number as a currency. All the content is on a table. At the moment, I have a class `money` in every `<tr>` and I call the function when the cell change. FYI, all the cells change at the same time in the table.

```
var spans = document.getElementsByClassName("money");
for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
    var newText = spans[i].innerHTML.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    spans[i].innerHTML = newText;
}
```

Is there any way instead of have the same class on every cell and catch an event on all of them, to do it on table and have the same result? For example,

```
$("#mytable").on('change', function() {
  // put my function here and apply to every cell
});
```

**Update**: I added the `DOMSubtreeModified` and tried to iterate through every cell in the table. However, even if I don't have any error on the console, it doesn't seem to work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#resultstable").bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {

      $('#resultstable tr').each(function() {
        $('td').each(function (i, cell) {
          cell.innerHTML.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");    
      });
    });
    });  

</script>
```

Comment: a table has no change event and a plain html table has no possibility of interact/change the contents, so i guess you use input elements inside the table ?

Comment: The `class=money` is on the `<tr>` of the table. And change the content of the `<td>`. I know that there isn't a "change" event for tables. That's why I ask if there is a way to do something like this

Comment: but how do you change the contents ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to use [DOMSubtreeModified](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMSubtreeModified) like,

```
$("#mytable").bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {
    alert("Hurrey table changed");
});
```

Read the [Dom-event-javascript article](http://davidwalsh.name/dom-events-javascript)

```js
$(function(){
    $('button').on('click',function(){
        $('#mytable').append('<tr><td>Next '+($('#mytable tr').length+1)+'</td></tr>');
    });
    $("#mytable").bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {
        alert("Hurrey table changed");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="mytable">
    <tr>
        <td>Next 1</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br/>
<button>Test</button>
```

Comment: Can you make an online demo for your code? Also, your both table-ids are conflicting.

Answer (score 2):

You could use setInterval() to monitor the table.

```
setInterval(function() { check(); }, 1000); //Call check() function every 1s.
```

In check() you would have some logic to compare.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    $(".money").each(function(indexOfElement, elementValue) {
        for (var i = 0; i < elementValue.length; i++) {
            var newText = elementValue[i].innerHTML.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
            $(elementValue).html(newText);
        }
    })

});
```

The above code iterates each element having class "money" and replaces the text with currency text. the script will run while the page is ready