# How to change the animation on change value angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, animation, angularjs-ng-click, ng-animate

I need to put an animation on change value on angularjs application. Basecally, i want to slide out left the old value and the new value has to display with a slide in left.

> 

```
    <div class="previous" ng-click="getPreviousTrainingsWeek()" ></div>

    <div class="content" ng-if="spy" >
        Semaine du {{timestamp.beginning_of_week | formatDateWithoutDay}}
    </div>

    <div class="next" ng-click="getNextTrainingsWeek()"></div>

</div>
```

Thanks everyone

Comment: And what is the question exactly? I guess you're looking for something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20053557/ng-animate-animation-when-model-changes)

Comment: No what I want to make the value slide from right to the left like a normal slider but it will slide only on change value